# Ansible fails with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pexpect'

Tags: python, ansible

I have three hosts, all running Ubuntu 18.04 with latest updates:

- master and staging are hosts that I have installed myself from an Ubuntu 18.04 image.
- prod is a host that I have leased from a provider, so I have no control on the basic installation beyond selecting Ubuntu 18.04.
- master has Ansible installed.

`ansible --version` yields:

```
ansible 2.9.6
  config file = /home/marco/Desktop/playbook/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/marco/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.17 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:07:09) [GCC 7.4.0]
```

`ansible.cfg` contains the line `interpreter_python = auto`.

My playbook works fine when run with target host staging. But when running with target host prod, it fails when running the [expect](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html) module:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pexpect'
fatal: [prod]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (pexpect) on prod's Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"}
```

I have tried to solve the problem by installing libries on master by

```sh
apt-get install python-pexpect
apt-get install python-pip
pip install pexpect
```

and on prod by adding

```yaml
- name: Install packages
  apt:
   name:
      - python-pexpect
      - python-pip
- name: Install Python modules
  command: pip install pexpect
```

to the playbook, but it did not help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the built-in `pip` Anisble module, it will detect which version of pip Ansible is using on the controlled node.

```
    - name: Install pip
      apt:
        update_cache: yes
        name:
          - python3-pip

    - name: Install pexpect
      pip:
        name: pexpect
```

Comment: Then, the pip module fails with `An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
fatal: [prod]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (setuptools) on prod's Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"}`

Comment: @MarcoEckstein , I've updated the code to ensure `pip` is set up

Comment: Now it works. Thanks a lot! I've got another error in my playbook, but I think it's unrelated.

Answer (score 4):

this is how i solved it

```
- name: Install pexpect
  pip:
     name: pexpect
  become: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install [geerlingguy.pip](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-pip) role from ansible galaxy with the following command :

```
ansible-galaxy install geerlingguy.pip
```

then add this on top of your playbook :

```
hosts: "{{myhost}}"
vars:
  pip_install_packages:
    - name: pexpect
  pip_package: python-pip
  pip_executable: pip
roles:
  - geerlingguy.pip
```

You can then use expect in ansible normally.